# How do I run a MATLAB script?

Tags: matlab

I have tried running a script in the MATLAB command line and it says

```
>> run(ex1)
Undefined function or variable 'ex1'.

>> run(exp1.m)
Undefined variable "exp1" or function "exp1.m".
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: just type the name of the script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `run` wrong.  You need to encapsulate the script name as a **string**:

```
>> run('ex1.m');
```

You'll need to make sure that your working directory is set to where the script is located, because the above way to call `run` assumes local referencing.

Please read the documentation on [`run`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/run.html) in the future: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/run.html

However, you can just type in `ex1` in the command prompt and it'll still work... as long as you're in the working directory of where the script is run, *and ensuring that you don't have any variables in your workspace that have the same name as the script file*:

```
>> ex1
```

Comment: "it'll still work" if it's in the path or current directory and as long as the user hasn't declared variables with the same name ;)

Comment: @excaza - It'll also work provided that the user didn't declare any variables called `ex1` :D